# How to include a view in a specific region defined in a custom layout?

Tags: views, blocks

I defined a set of views that I would like to include in specific regions ordered in a particular way through a custom layout. However, the block menu does not allow me to select these regions. All I can do is to give an order (1, 2, 3, etc.) to these views, which does not solve my problem because I need the views' outcomes to show up in these specific areas of the page.

I've looked up in many places but I couldn't find any answer to that question. Someone could give me a hint?

Thanks a lot!
Igor

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13297/insert-a-views-block-into-a-node-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 0):

You can embed views anywhere with php with views_embed_view(). Please refer https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!  I had seen these threads but as I am really new with site building, I am looking for interface-based solutions. I would love to understand the type of solution you mentioned, and I tried! But I get lost easily, I don't even know where to put the code! Anyway, I found a very straightforward solution to my problem: I used the EVA (Entity Views Attachment) module. I created EVA fields in each of my views and allocated them in the regions I wanted. Great module for a simple solution... Thanks again!