# How to access block fields programmatically?

Tags: 7, blocks

I display a block of type **Assignment** on the top of a page when I'm creating a node of type **Submission**.  I need to access the fields of the **Assignment block** programmatically with my custom module.

**Are there any built in Drupal functions that will allow me to do so?**

I'm currently using `hook_form_alter()` but that does not give me access to the block elements.

Comment: What version of Drupal is it? How did you make your blocks fieldable? What module provides them? Views? Node Blocks? Sth else?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7, the block is made from a view -> it displays another another node

Comment: This sounds pretty similar to this [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13297/insert-a-views-block-into-a-node-in-drupal-7) asking about injecting content of a views block into a node.

Comment: I don't think it's similar. Poster wants to access a node field inside of a Views block, not insert a Views block inside of a node field. :)

Comment: Ah, I knew this sounded familiar: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/170528/28700. @Matt why open a new question when this has already been answered for you? If the answer is unsatisfactory, just reframe the question or ask for more clarification.

Comment: @Matt edit details into your question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the value by first grabbing the assignment value from the URL, then looking up the path to find the node id, then loading that node and using a wrapper to find the value of that specific field.

```
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $pos = strpos($url, '?') + 1;
        $assignment = substr($url, $pos, strlen($url)); //get the assignment from the URL

        $nodeID = drupal_lookup_path('source', "student-assignments-new/" . $assignment);//get the path from the assignment - e.g. node/145
        $pos = strpos($nodeID, '/') + 1;
        $nid = substr($nodeID, $pos, strlen($nodeID));//get the node id

        $node = node_load($nid);

        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node); 
        $fieldValue = $wrapper->field_file_type_text->value();

        $output = $node->field_file_type_text[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; //field_file_type_text is my own field name
        return $output;
```

Comment: The striked lines initially worked for me, but whenever I uploaded a file - I would get an AJAX error and a 500 internal server error. The lines below it fixed the issue.